# How can jQuery load some html and append it to the <body> element?

Tags: jquery, load

I tried the following:

```
$.load("Views/chatBox.html").appendTo('body')
```

Console Output:

```
TypeError: $.load is not a function
```

**EDIT**: The answer should only be one line of code; that's enough, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dont understand why placing container at the bottom of body and loading external page into that is not what you need?

What you can try is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#container").load("Views/chatBox.html",function(){
            $(this).clone().appendTo("body").remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But im not 100% sure about this code... :)

Comment: So,Must jQuery bother some element to do ajax things?

Comment: Well you must always have some selector onto which something will be done. Some demo page or code would help in understanding what you want, but that previus answer is, i think, what you need. :)

Answer (score 83):

Nope, all those answers are incorrect because they rely on having a separate container!

Do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your.html",
    success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

Comment: +1, this exactly appends the content to BODY, thx for sharing!

Comment: I have small datepicker that show the current date and the next day.  
I used what you wrote, but having problem, the problem is that the data is not update, but when I refresh the page it update.
I using wordpress and plugin allow to run jQuery.

Comment: @hanan-mstudio That seems like a whole other question and probably not related at all to the answer I gave. Can you post a new question?

Comment: Why is this down here when this seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: wohoo .. so nice, quick 'n tidy :) maybe use .html(data) instead of append()?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution:

```
jQuery('#AppendToMe').append( jQuery('<div>').load(...) );
```

This will append whatever you load into the #AppendToMe element.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried out GaVrA's solution I found it could be even simpler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#container").load("external.html").appendTo("body");;        
    });
</script>
```

I guess appentTo automatically removes a previous instance? Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("body").load("Views/chatBox.html");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "Load HTML from a remote file and inject it into the DOM."

So you just need some selector into which injection will be done. ;)

Aka - yes, load does the work of appending.

Check out that demo i made and posted and that tutorial, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Oh,no,it will replace the whole page with Views/chatBox.html,which is not what I desired.I need to append it to <body>.

Comment: Well what i am doing is having some container, in that demo it is #majice, and it is empty. Then i load external page into that. Makes sense?

Comment: Not exactly the same as what I desired.My case:1.no container 2.get html by ajax and append it to <body>

Comment: If there is a container,I can do this:$('#container').load(...).appendTo('body').Right?But I need to implement it without container.