# How to load some html and append to <body> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

It is related to the question here: [How to load some html and append to <body> with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385641/how-to-load-some-html-and-append-to-body-with-jquery/4867469?noredirect=1#comment44516012_4867469)

I been asked to open new question

my problem is:

I have small datepicker that show the current date and the next day. I used the code posted there, but having problem, the problem is that the data is not update, but when I refresh the page it update. I using wordpress and plugin allow to run jQuery

the code that posted there is

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your.html",
    success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Inside the success callback, add on console.log(data); Your data result may not be up to date.

Comment: Not a short answer for this one. Must it update on a click, on a hover, on a timer? When must it update? All the answers for each case are simple, but different.

Comment: r u sure that ur ajax call is returning html ? put a `console.log(data)` in ur success function and check in console in DevTools if its fine

Comment: I need the show the datepicker every time someone visit the page. I insert it into the (document).ready(function() section, but it not showing the correct date until I refresh the page but sometime it showing it on the first try

Answer (score 1):

this may help 
this will automatically update the code after every 200ms after the page is loaded

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 done();
});

function done() {
  setTimeout( function() { 
  updates(); 
  done();
  }, 200);//set timer
```

}

```
function updates() {
     // add your code here to update
```

}

Comment: `setTimeout()` will invoke a function only once. You have to use `setInterval()` to invoke some function at regular intevals :) . Although there's no guarantee it will invoke for every 200ms, that's the minimum it waits to invoke that function, it can be even more - depending your whether your JS thread is busy doing something else