# Jquery ajax append html file based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

so far i have a simple script to include few html files on all pages. What i would like to achieve is to include specific file based on the folder in the url that visitor is currently on and define those folder names, for example:

- If /page-1/index-1.html (include demo-1.html)
- If /page-1/index-2.html (include demo-1.html)
- If /random-page/test.html (include demo-1.html)
- If /page-2/index-1.html (include demo-2.html)
- If /page-2/index-2.html (include demo-2.html)
- If /another-folder/test.html (include demo-2.html)
- ... and so on

Currently i include both demo-1.html and demo-2.html on all pages, but this is not working for me as the content inside those two files is different per folder. The script i use:

`$.ajax({
    url: "../include/demo-1.html",
    success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html'
});`

Any help appricieted, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help from a stackoverflow user who posted an answer in a similar thread found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385641/how-to-load-some-html-and-append-to-body-with-jquery/4867469#4867469), i've came up with a working solution (not sure if it's optimised well, but it works):

```
$(function() {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    if(/folder-name/.test(currentURL)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../include/demo-1.html",
            success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    };
    if(/another-folder-name/.test(currentURL)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../include/demo-2.html",
            success: function (data) { $('body').append(data); },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    };
    // etc...
});
```

Hope this helps someone else with same question.